# Data type clash

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void reverseOrder (double []);

int main() {

    const int size = 4;

    double array[size] = {1.2, 6.7, -12.45, 34.9};

    cout << "Forwards:" << " " << endl;

    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        cout << array[index] << endl;
    }

    // Display in reversed order.
    cout << "Backwards: " << endl;
    reverseOrder(array[size]);

    return 0;
}

void reverseOrder(double array[]) {

    const int size = 10;
    int j;
    double reverseOrder[size];
    double temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < (size / 2); i++, j--) {
        temp = reverseOrder[i];
        reverseOrder[i] = array[j];
        reverseOrder[j] = temp;
    }

    for (int reverse = 0; reverse < size; reverse++) {
        cout << array[reverse] << endl;
    }
}
```

error C2664: 'void reverseOrder(double [])' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to 'double []'
error is here ---> reverseOrder(array[size]);

Comment: Argh. This is so brash, rude, disrespectful and childish that it's funny. What makes you think you will ever get an answer on a question that was not even asked? Pro-Advice: At least look at the FAQ first ...

Comment: why it doesn't want to compile? Use --force-to-compile directive

Comment: In `main()` you called `reverseOrader(array[size])` which means you are passing an element of an array but your function is expecting an array of elements. Try `reverseOrder(array)`.

Comment: BTW, after you fix that you have some UB to deal with.. Hint: size is 4 in main and 10 in reverseOrder()

Comment: @DanielAwbrey: If you would take the time to state an actual question, and generally put some more time into formulating a neat text, instead of vomitting a clump of text without even looking at the preview, you will attract way more ppl to write you up a nice answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your function `reverseOrder(double[])` with `array[size]` as argument which is only one element of the array(*). So you are passing a double but the function expects an array.

In your case you should call the function with `reverseOrder(array)`.

(*)in this case it is not even an element because it points to the element **after** the last one because the first element is accessed by 0 and so by 4 you would actually access the 5th element (thanks to drescherjm for pointing that out)

Comment: ***which is only one element of the array*** Actually it's an element outside the array/UB since c/c++ uses 0 based indexing.

Comment: Correct. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular problem (just the first one from what we can observe) is that you are trying to pass a single `double` to a function expecting the *array of `double`s*. It is because

```
array[index]
```

returns a value of the array associated with given index (you should call this like `reverseOrder(array);`). That is, it returns this as long as the index is in the allowed range. This is not the case here, because array[size] is one past the last element of the array. The last one is indexed array[size-1]. Thus you are experiencing **undefined behavior**.